# Django append parameter to an url which include model name

Tags: django

#### admin.py

```
class TopicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['ID','Name','Show_Report']
    actions = ['show_report']

    def Show_Report(self, obj):      # obj is the object of Topic you selected
        return mark_safe('''<a  style="background: url(\'/site_media/img/tooltag-arrowright_over.gif\') no-repeat scroll 0 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); padding-left: 24px;" href="showReport/%s">Report</a>'''%obj.ID)
```

This is a link in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/myproject/topic/`, and then i click the link, it will go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/myproject/topic/showReport/1`.
so i add url in `url.py` like below:

#### urls.py

```
url(r'^admin/myproject/topic/showReport/1', hello),
```

But then it goes to error `topic object with primary key u'showReport' does not exist`.
If i use below

#### admin.py

```
return  .....<a href="../showReport/1"><a/>
```

#### urls.py

```
url(r'^admin/myproject/showReport/1', hello)
```

then it works.
Can you tell me what is the reason, and what should i do if i want yo use the first URL

Comment: please post your complete code.

Comment: do you want any other code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass `showReport` as a PrimaryKey. A PrimaryKey is a number. So as far as I can understand what you're trying to do here you should use:

```
url(r'^admin/myproject/topic/1', hello)
```

IMHO: Please do the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) and have a look at [python design guides](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You're doing a lot of mistakes like [capitalized function names](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names), field names and you're far away from [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). [Test your code online](http://pep8online.com) or google for other tools. Please don't be mad at me, I'm just trying to get you into the right direction - and as far as I can see you need to learn some python basics.